# Rails Destroy not working after adding Bootstrap with Webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, webpacker

I am creating a rails project and I am having a couple of issues.

### What I've done so far

Firstly I added bootstrap to the project using cdn links in the `application.html.erb` file in layouts. This gave me the formatting I needed and worked fine HOWEVER, due to turbo-links the javascript required for drop-down navigation stopped working when a page was changed.

To fix this I used Webpacker and followed the tutorial here https://www.bootrails.com/blog/rails-bootstrap-tutorial/ to get bootstrap and the required javascript required working as intended.

### The problem I now face

Now that I have added in bootstrap, some of the sinks to destroy records no longer work.

The code below, rather than displaying popup and destroying the record as it did previously, now takes me to the record and displays it.

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', emergency_contact, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

### Console logs

When I click the above link the following is outputted in the rails server console.

```
Started GET "/emergency_contacts/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-06-15 11:01:48 +0100
Processing by EmergencyContactsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  EmergencyContact Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "emergency_contacts".* FROM "emergency_contacts" WHERE "emergency_contacts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/emergency_contacts_controller.rb:63:in `set_emergency_contact'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering emergency_contacts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered emergency_contacts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 128)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:45
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 7.6ms | Allocations: 3648)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 7.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 4591)
```

### Bits of code

I've included bits of code that I think are relevant to the problem I'm facing

###### config/webpacker.yml

Changed `source_path: app/javascript` to `source_path: app/frontend`

###### app/frontend/packs/application.scss

contents:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

###### app/frontend/packs/application.js

contents:

```
import '../js/bootstrap_js_files.js'
```

###### app/frontend/js/bootstrap_js_files.js

contents:

```
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/alert'  
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/button'  
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/carousel'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/collapse'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/dropdown'  
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/modal'  
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/popover'  
import 'bootstrap/js/src/scrollspy'  
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/tab'  
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/toast'  
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/tooltip'
```

###### app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

head:

```
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

   <!-- Warning !! ensure that "stylesheet_pack_tag" is used, line below -->
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

Dropdown:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    dd links
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dd link 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dd link 2</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dd link 3</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">dd link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `link_to` to `button_to`

```rb
<%= link_to 'Destroy', emergency_contact, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

to:

```rb
<%= button_to 'Destroy', emergency_contact, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

If `confirm` is still not working you can add `onclick` option

```rb
<%= button_to 'Destroy', emergency_contact, method: :delete, onclick: "return confirm('Are you
sure?')" %>
```

Update:

For working `link_to` with options `method: :delete` and `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` is responsible this gem [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) and in previous Rails versions it was included in `assets/javascripts/application.js` file

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Since you are using `javascript_pack_tag` with `Webpacker` and your entry point is `javascript/packs/application.js` not `assets/javascripts/application.js` so that to make it works you need to install `yarn add jquery-ujs` and import it in `javascript/packs/application.js` file

```js
import { } from "jquery-ujs"
```

And after that you will be able to use `link_to` with `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` and `method: :delete`

Comment: That deletes the record however it doesn't display the confirmation popup as it did previously, how would I force the popup to display?

Comment: What Rails version do you use?

Comment: Try `data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` if you are using Rails 7

Comment: Currently running on 6.1.6

Comment: Do you have any js errors in `web console`?

Comment: Nope, all clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245625/discussion-between-stefanyuk-yuriy-and-conor).

Comment: Check my update plz

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked

Comment: Let's go to the chat